# Japanese Suitmation Monster Movie

Tags: story-identification

I know this one is going to be tough to identify, but it's something I saw as a kid and I've always wondered what the movie was like.  I took it seriously as a kid, but suspect I'd laugh my head off at it now.  I saw it in the late 1960s or early 1970s on a local monster movie show.  From what I've seen since, I'm sure this was Japanese suitmation.

There were two monsters in this movie (or at least two) and one was bad and one was good.  The bad one was like a pterodactyl and could fly.  It also fired a laser beam from its mouth.  I remember a scene where, before the bad monster revealed itself, a twin-rotor helicopter (as in one rotor at each end) was carrying a number of people who were viewing an area for some reason and it was shot with a laser beam that sliced it in half, and people started faling out of each end of the helicopter.

The other monster was some kind of reptile, on two or four legs.  I remember it rearing up, so it was able to at least stand on two legs temporarily.  There were shots during the battle where the bad monster hit it with a laser beam and water was pouring out of the wound.

I know it was a "versus" movie.  I thought it might be *Godzilla vs. Megalon*, but it isn't.

I know that's not much to go on, but it'd be great if someone could tell me what this movie was.

Comment: the correct fan-geek term is Dai Kaijyu Tokusatsu ;-)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Gamera vs. Gyaos
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamera_vs._Gaos

The best version is from MST3K, although it was remade for the new Gamera movies

Gamera was of course a giant flying Turtle.  When Gyaos' laser hit Gamera he would bleed bluish blood.

Comment: Interesting that the blood is bluish -- I should have included that at the time my family only had a black and white TV, so I might not have noticed any coloring.  Thanks!